# Set scrollLeft based on the Weekday number

Tags: jquery, html, css, date

I was wondering how to set `.scrollLeft()` based on the day of the week.

I figured out that I could get the weekday number by using `Date().getdate()`. Which would return **0** for Sunday and **6** for Saturday.

However, I'm working on a horizontally scrolling schedule. The schedule is in a `700%` width div. Monday starts at `left: 0`. If the user clicks on Tuesday the div scrolls `100%` to the right to show Tuesday. So far that all works, although my jQuery could be a bit more straight forward (currently I loop over the buttons with `eq(0)`, `eq(1)`, `eq(2)` etc).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".daypick li a").eq(0).on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".calendar").css({left: 0});
    });
    $(".daypick li a").eq(1).on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action of anchor
        $(".calendar").css({left: "-100%"}); 
    });
    $(".daypick li a").eq(2).on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action of anchor
        $(".calendar").css({left: "-200%"}); //Animates the scroll
    /* Can also use 3000, 4000 i.e 3 seconds, 4 seconds to animate the scroll */
    });
    $(".daypick li a").eq(3).on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action of anchor
        $(".calendar").css({left: "-300%"}); //Animates the scroll
    /* Can also use 3000, 4000 i.e 3 seconds, 4 seconds to animate the scroll */
    });
    $(".daypick li a").eq(4).on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action of anchor
        $(".calendar").css({left: "-400%"}); //Animates the scroll
    /* Can also use 3000, 4000 i.e 3 seconds, 4 seconds to animate the scroll */
    });
    $(".daypick li a").eq(5).on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action of anchor
        $(".calendar").css({left: "-500%"}); //Animates the scroll
    /* Can also use 3000, 4000 i.e 3 seconds, 4 seconds to animate the scroll */
    });
    $(".daypick li a").eq(6).on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action of anchor
        $(".calendar").css({left: "-600%"}); //Animates the scroll
    /* Can also use 3000, 4000 i.e 3 seconds, 4 seconds to animate the scroll */
    });
    $(".daypick li a").eq(7).on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default action of anchor
        $(".calendar").css({left: "-700%"}); //Animates the scroll
    /* Can also use 3000, 4000 i.e 3 seconds, 4 seconds to animate the scroll */
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is that the script checks which day it is and shows the schedule for that day. So on Wednesday the parent div should get `left: -300%` and the third button should get class `active`.

However I'm a bit stuck with the dates. My first idea was to take the weekday number and multiply it with **100** to get the `left` value. The problem is that Sunday returns **0**, and in my case I would need Monday to return **0** for that to function.

Hopefully someone can provide some help.

I've created a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zLxf3cuy/1/),

Comment: Just make a function to "translate" the "day number" you get to the "day number" you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the day based on monday using `(currentDay + 6) % 7`.

**important point** Don't bind individual event for each link. Do it generic - find the link's index using jQuery [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) then multiply it with `100`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var links = $(".daypick li a").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var index = links.index(this);
    $(".calendar").css({left: -(index*100) + '%'});
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    var currentDay = new Date().getDay();
    links.eq((currentDay + 6) % 7).trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.daypick {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.daypick li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.daypick li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #3ab3b6;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;

  transition: all .3s;
}

.daypick li a:hover, .daypick li a.active {
  background: #268a8d;
}

.calendar-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.calendar {
  width: 700%;
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 2s;
  left: 0;
}

.weekday {
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  float: left;
}

.raumwrap {
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.raum1, .raum2 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
  max-width:100%;
  margin-right: 75px;
}

.raum1 td, .raum2 td {
  padding: 10px 5px; 
}

.raum1 tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #3ab3b6;
  color: #fff;
}

.raum1 tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #fff;
}

.raum2 tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #268a8d;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="daypick">
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Montag</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dienstag</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mittwoch</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Donnerstag</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Freitag</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Samstag</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sonntag</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="calendar-wrapper">
      <main class="calendar">
        <div class="weekday">
          <h1>Montag:</h1>

          <div class="raumwrap">
            <h2>Raum 1</h2>
            <table class="raum1">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Zeit</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Kurse</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Therapeut</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>07:00 - 08:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>08:00 - 09:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>15:00 - 16:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>17:00 - 18:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>19:00 - 20:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="raumwrap">
            <h2>Raum 2</h2>
            <table class="raum2">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Zeit</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Kurse</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Therapeut</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>07:00 - 08:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>08:00 - 09:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>15:00 - 16:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>17:00 - 18:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>19:00 - 20:00</td>
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>Krankengymnastiek</td> 
                  <td width="50"></td>
                  <td>John Doe</td> 
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="weekday">
          <h1>Dienstag:</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="weekday">
          <h1>Mittwoch:</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="weekday">
          <h1>Donnerstag:</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="weekday">
          <h1>Freitag:</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="weekday">
          <h1>Samstag:</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="weekday">
          <h1>Sonntag:</h1>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9fgwoxpm/1/

Comment: Thanks, I just got it working, but your solution is far more efficient/elegant. Marked as answer! Can I ask what use `setTimeout(function(){` is in this case?

Comment: @laurens1991 My pleasure.. The `setTimeout` is for the animation. If we remove it the transition will not occur. I don't 100% sure about the mechanism but: A. `setTimeout` is the best friend of a man :) B. I think that for the transition work, the element need to be without the class active then add it. Without `setTimeout` the browser is not "recognize" that the `.active` class was added.

Answer (score 0):

As my original code is already slightly bloated / large I guess I can live with the below solution:

```
var weekday = new Date().getDay();

if (weekday === 0) {
    $(".calendar").css({left: "-700%"});
} else if (weekday === 1) {
    $(".calendar").css({left: 0});
} else if (weekday === 2) {
    $(".calendar").css({left: "-100%"});
} else if (weekday === 3) {
    $(".calendar").css({left: "-200%"});
} else if (weekday === 4) {
    $(".calendar").css({left: "-300%"});
} else if (weekday === 5) {
    $(".calendar").css({left: "-400%"});
} else if (weekday === 6) {
    $(".calendar").css({left: "-500%"});
} else {
    $(".calendar").css({left: 0});
}
```

it does what it should, there might be more efficient ways to loop through the list but for now it works!